# Sequelize many-to-many self association

Tags: javascript, orm, sequelize.js

I am trying to create a model `Users` with many-to-many association to itself to allow users to follow another users. In one query I want to retrieve the `Users` followed by the current user; in another query I want to retrieve the people that follows the current user.

This is my `Users` model:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const Users = sequelize.define(
        'Users',
        {
            id: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                autoIncrement: true,
                primaryKey: true,
            },

            name: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING,
            },
        },
    );
    Users.associate = function(models) {
        Users.belongsToMany(Users, { as: 'following', through: models.UsersUsers });
    };

    return Users;
};
```

I declare `UsersUsers`, just in case I need to add any field there:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const UsersUsers = sequelize.define(
        'UsersUsers',
        {}
    );
    UsersUsers.associate = function(models) {};

    return UsersUsers;
};
```

Then I query `Users` as:

```
models.Users.findOne({
    where: {
        id: req.params.id,
    },
    include: [
        {
            model: models.Users,
            as: 'following',
        },
    ],
})
    .then((results) => {
        return res.send({
            User: results,
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        return res.send(String(error));
    });
```

And I get this result:

```
{
    "User": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "User1",
        "following": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "User2",
                "UsersUsers": {
                    "UserId": 1,
                    "followingId": 2
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "User3",
                "UsersUsers": {
                    "UserId": 1,
                    "followingId": 3
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "User4",
                "UsersUsers": {
                    "UserId": 1,
                    "followingId": 4
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Now the questions:

1. In my current query, how do I exclude "UsersUsers" from the result? `attributes: { exclude: ['UsersUsers'] }` did not work…
2. How do I create a query to retrieve the current user with the users that follows him instead of the users followed by him?

Thanks!

--
EDIT:

The solution for the question 1. is to add `through: { attributes: [] }` to the included model:

```
models.Users.findOne({
    where: {
        id: req.params.id,
    },
    include: [
        {
            model: models.Users,
            as: 'following',
            through: {
                attributes: [],
            },
        },
    ],
})
    .then((results) => {
        return res.send({
            User: results,
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        return res.send(String(error));
    });
```

Still pending question 2!

Comment: Can you show an example for question 2 to more clear?

Comment: Thanks @ChuongTran: I think that the current example —users following users— is the best one. Try to implement it, you will see it at once ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
Users.findAll({
        include: [
    {
        model: models.Users,
        as: 'following',
        through: {
            attributes: [],
        },
    },
],
    where : {
        id : [connection.literal(` write raw sql query to get followingId here`)]
    }
})
.then(result => {
    res.json(result);
}).catch(error=>{
    res.json(error);
});
```

I'm not sure if this gonna work, still play around this and do let me know if this worked or if you found any solution.